# HP Procurve - Configure Voice VLAN

Tags: vlan, hp, hp-procurve, voice

I have a HP 2810-48G that I would like to configure for a voice vlan. On our other HP switches (2800, 2610, 2530, etc.) I would navigate to the correct vlan and then type "voice".

On the 2810 when I do this I get "invalid input: voice". I've looked for an explantion and found a post that says that LLDP-MED is not supported on the 2800 series. Yet, I have it working on a 2824 (J4903A Configuration Editor; Created on release #I.10.77). Any ideas? Perhaps my 2810 has an old firmware? It is running firmware #N.11.64. It is hard to understand why this feature would work on a 2824 and not the newer 2810-48G - what am I missing?

Comment: As I recall there are some older switches that supported a voice vlan feature, but that only really dealt with enabling a specific set of QoS features, and did not allow for all the niceties of LLDP-MED such as dynamically providing the VLAN ID to a phone. Any chance that's what's happening on your 2824 ? I do not recall anything from either of those switch models that suggests it provides "modern" voice vlan support.

Comment: One of the message board posts that I found said that the "voice" command could be entered but that it doesn't work. I have it configured on the 2824 but it may have never been tested since I don't typically plug VOIP phones into that switch. I use it / want to use it only to dynamically set the phones VLAN.

Comment: Without LLDP-MED or (assuming Cisco phones) CDP with support for assigning the VLAN dynamically, which neither of those switches seems to have, I don't think you'll be able to do that.

Comment: Phones are Polycom SountPoint. I guess that I will have to configure the VLAN manually per port on this switch.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I just checked, the voice option is not available on a 2810-24G running software  N.11.69. You can still set the QoS values manually though.